# How to save the transform matrix in GLKit?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

In iOS 5, with EAGLView, you can do:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();
```

With GLKView, is this replaced by the following?

```
GLKMatrix4 t = self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix;

self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(t, x, y, 0);
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = t;
```

Kind of ugly...

Comment: I think the GLKit is mainly targeted for programmers who uses the programmable pipeline, not the fixed pipeline.

Comment: And is there a way in GLKit to push/pop the state without using a temporary variable?

Comment: If you're using the fixed pipeline, you might be better off not using GLKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [GLKMatrixStack](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrixStack/Reference/reference.html). I use this for building hierarchical models in GLKit.